# Java game walking + jumping stops the key pressing action?

Tags: java, 2d

Hello in my game when I walk and jump, it stops everything after the jump finishes:

[image: not hotlinked image]

Can you see after a jump, it continues walking for a bit & then stops?
It should stop immediately but my walking queue continues executing because I didn't reset it, it should only reset upon keypress or release. But keypressing will stop working after i release my jump key. I think if I use  2 keys at a time and release on, the OS won't remember the old key I am still pressing. Even in your browser URL input, press and any key and hold, and then hold another key for bit & release it, it won't write the old key anymore.

Is there a fix for this? I am using keylistener, because i couldn't figure out how to find out when a key was released in KeyBinds.

This is how I do it:

```
public class Keyboard implements KeyListener {

    private Player player;

    public Keyboard(Player p) {
        this.player = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("yes");
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {

            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                this.player.getMovement().moveLeft();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                this.player.getMovement().moveRight();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
                this.player.getMovement().jump();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int left = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
        int right = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == left || e.getKeyCode() == right) {
            this.player.getMovement().stopMovement();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

How can I fix this issue? If you need more parts of the code like the jump or walking queue, let me know.

Keylog:

```
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Right clicked!
Space is a nice button
```

Comment: you mentioned the OS won't remember the old key I am still pressing. What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 @ExcelledProducts

Comment: i think it is because you are holding the key down. (up and right at the same time). Can you put println statments in your vb left, right and space and show the log. I think that will help

Comment: @ExcelledProducts Yes I always press the Right arrow, while I also press the space to jump

Comment: can you try without. Go right jump then go right and see if it happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47566/discussion-between-excelledproducts-and-user3123545)

Comment: Make sure that when you are holding down 2 keys that you have a array of boolean's, keys that are already pressed. So if you have 2 true boolean's then you do both actions one by one. Once you let go of the which ever key the boolean gets set to false.

Comment: Don't process moveRight() moveLeft() jump() in keyPressed, simply set boolean's in array there.. but do the actual processing in a different Thread which accesses the boolean array, that way it will feel like realtime actions.

Comment: `I am using keylistener, because i couldn't figure out how to find out when a key was released in KeyBinds.` - You have been given working code in your other question. You never take the time to listen to the help or reply when you get help, so I'll skip this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember process all the keypresses in a separate Thread.

http://wiki.processing.org/w/Multiple_key_presses

Method #1

```
/**
multiplekeys taken from http://wiki.processing.org/index.php?title=Keep_track_of_multiple_key_presses
@author Yonas Sandbæk http://seltar.wliia.org
*/

// usage: 
// if(checkKey("ctrl") && checkKey("s")) println("CTRL+S");  

boolean[] keys = new boolean[526];
void draw(){}
boolean checkKey(String k)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++)
    if(KeyEvent.getKeyText(i).toLowerCase().equals(k.toLowerCase())) return keys[i];  
  return false;
}

void keyPressed()
{ 
  keys[keyCode] = true;
  println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode));
}

void keyReleased()
{ 
  keys[keyCode] = false; 
}
```

Methord #2 (And a simpler way of doing this just checking a few keys (without an array))

```
boolean keyup = false;
boolean keyright = false;
boolean keyleft = false;
boolean keydown = false;

float x,y;

void setup() {
  size(640,360);  
  x = width/2;
  y = height/2;
}

void draw() {
  background(51);
  fill(255);
  ellipse(x,y,16,16);

  if (keyup) y--;
  if (keydown) y++;
  if (keyleft) x--;
  if (keyright) x++;


}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == UP) keyup = true; 
    if (keyCode == DOWN) keydown = true; 
    if (keyCode == LEFT) keyleft = true; 
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) keyright = true; 
  }
}

void keyReleased() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == UP) keyup = false; 
    if (keyCode == DOWN) keydown = false; 
    if (keyCode == LEFT) keyleft = false; 
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) keyright = false; 
  }
}
```

Method #3

```
/**
Modified version of Option 1 multiplekeys (should provide improved performance and accuracy)
@author Yonas Sandbæk http://seltar.wliia.org (modified by jeffg)
*/

// usage: 
// if(checkKey(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) && checkKey(KeyEvent.VK_S)) println("CTRL+S");  

boolean[] keys = new boolean[526];

void draw(){}

boolean checkKey(int k)
{
  if (keys.length >= k) {
    return keys[k];  
  }
  return false;
}

void keyPressed()
{ 
  keys[keyCode] = true;
  println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode));
  if(checkKey(CONTROL) && checkKey(KeyEvent.VK_S)) println("CTRL+S");
}

void keyReleased()
{ 
  keys[keyCode] = false; 
}
```

Method #5

```
  /**
   * Snappier multiple key detection using Primitive Collections Classes for Java http://pcj.sourceforge.net/
   * (standard Java Collection Objects can be used instead)
   * @author analogAI http://recursivepath.com/analogAI/
   */

   // usage:
   // if(this.checkKeysHeld(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL) && this.checkKeysHeld(KeyEvent.VK_S)) println("CTRL+S");  

import bak.pcj.set.IntSet;
import bak.pcj.set.IntOpenHashSet;

public class HelloWorld extends PApplet {

  public IntSet keysheld = new IntOpenHashSet();
  /**
   * @param keycode key integer code, the value are constants defined in KeyEvent Class
   *                http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html
   *                e.g. KeyEvent.VK_A for letter A
   *                     KeyEvent.VK_0 for number 0
   *                     KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT for shift button
   * @return true if the key is currently held down, false otherwise
   */

  public boolean checkKeysHeld(int keycode){
    return this.keysheld.contains(keycode);
  }

  public void keyPressed(){
    // add key to the list of keys held down
    // with processing, the KeyEvent object is always available as "keyEvent",
    // the getKeyChar() is already in the variable 'key', and getKeyCode() is in the variable 'keyCode'.
    this.keysheld.add(this.keyEvent.getKeyCode());
    println("key pressed: "+KeyEvent.getKeyText(this.keyEvent.getKeyCode()));
    println("keys in current held list: "+this.keysheld.toString());
  }

  public void keyReleased(){
    // remove key from the list of keys held down
    this.keysheld.remove(this.keyEvent.getKeyCode());
  }
}
```